# Special character not getting correctly from Searchbar

Tags: swift, search, uisearchbar

I'm sending *Oven D'* word into the search reqeust paramters.

If I'm passing static value (Oven D') into the post alamofire request it's working fine. The request of this paramter is like this

```
"Keyword" = "Oven D\'"
```

But if I'm sending it form searchBar.text then it will not work and my request is something like this

```
"Keyword" = "Oven D'"
```

Please suggest me why this happening. Is there I need to change something in Search bar property.

Thanks in Advance for suggesting or helping me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue of symbols entering from the search keyboard.
I'm entering *'* this but actually it was technically entered *,* in upwords direction

I used following code and it works:

```
searchBar.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: "’", with: "'")
```